# Assign the value to Variable SendTo for automatic email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have written those codes to send automatic email from excel if the condition which is applied on **Column Q** and this condition says if the number of days is greater than 2 , the automatic email will be sent to the Agent email in Column **"C"** *within the same row of the condition* which is met in Column Q. Now, the below codes run , but it is sent to the agent email in only cell 5 of the column "C" ; however, my goal is to send to agent email in column "C" when the condition is met in column Q within the same Row . Please advise .

```
Dim xRg As Range


'Update by Extendoffice 2018/3/7
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  Set xRg = Intersect(Range("Q5:Q1000"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 2 Then
     
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    End If
    
  
    
    
End Sub
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Dim sendTo As Variant


sendTo = Range("C5").Value


    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Hi" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "This is a reminder that you have one past due Qoutation Request " & vbNewLine & _
              "its details as per the following , please take an instant action :"
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
         
        .To = sendTo
        
        .Subject = "send by cell value test"
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you could do this.

Here's one that uses the module level variable `xRg`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim xRg As Range

'Update by Extendoffice 2018/3/7
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Set xRg = Intersect(Range("Q5:Q1000"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 2 Then

        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    End If

End Sub

Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
Dim xOutApp As Object
Dim xOutMail As Object
Dim xMailBody As String
Dim sendTo As Variant

    sendTo = Intersect(Range("C:C"), xRg.EntireRow).Value

    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Hi" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                "This is a reminder that you have one past due Qoutation Request " & vbNewLine & _
                "its details as per the following , please take an instant action :"
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail

        .To = sendTo

        .Subject = "send by cell value test"
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```